# Change title of browser window in Vaadin 8

Tags: window, vaadin, title, vaadin8

How does one change the title seen in the client web browser window or tab title bar in a [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) 8 app?

- When I set the content of the initial [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) with my `Layout` object, how can I specify a title for that UI’s window?
- If I open another browser window/tab with another `UI`, how do I set the title in the native title bar of that window/tab?

Comment: Page.getCurrent().setTitle("Tab title");  should do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although at the time of this writing the official version listed is 7.7.7 this applies for 8 as well, so as per the [documentation, there's a dedicate `@Title` annotation](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/Title.html).

[image: Vaadin doc version]

Alternatively as Vikrant Thakur's comment is suggesting, you can also use [`Page.getCurrent().setTitle("whatever")`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-) to dynamically update it.

Below you can see in action a sample based on the default app generated by the [Vaadin maven archetype 8.0.0_rc1](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-8-beta-is-out-we-need-your-help-):

[image: Vaadin - set page title]