# Changing page title (browser tab) dynamically in vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I know in Vaadin 14 I can use the `@PageTitle` annotation (among other things) to change the title displayed in the browser tab on navigation changes - I got this to work when I was trying to upgrade my Vaadin 7 application.  I also know that in Vaadin 7, I can use the `@Title` annotation to change the UI title.  Is there a way in Vaadin 7 to do something similar to what we can do with `@PageTitle` in Vaadin 14?  I just tried setting the title for a given `View` using `@Title`, and it did not work.

According to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42226568/3329922), I can do it using something like `Page.getCurrent().setTitle("title");`, and this seems to work for Vaadin 7, but I want to confirm this is the best way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. You've simply repeated the tag information along with the words *Page title*, which is not in any way meaningful. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your current title does nothing in that regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Page.getCurrent().setTitle("title");`  is the way to go.